# What does the phrase "scientific studies of statistically significant samples of people" mean exactly?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"And we would urge the reader to do the same, while pointing to scientific studies of statistically significant samples of people that suggest Smith is right: the Easterlin Paradox, for example, is widely recognized." (Jonathan Conlin, *Critical Lives-Adam Smith*)

Comment: In statistical studies, you measure something on a random sample.  In this case, a random sample of people, because Adam Smith was asserting something about people.  "Statistically significant" means that the random sample is large enough that the the conclusion we observe is unlkely to be mere coincidence.

Comment: You need to look at hypothesis testing in statistics, and criteria for designing / conducting meaningful surveys (both off-topic here on ELU). Also, how to research two sides of a debate when both sides seem authoritative but disagree.

Comment: Google  "statistically significant"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of Smith's observations was that:

> "the condition of the labouring poor, of the great body of the people, seems to be the happiest and the most comfortable".
>
> [Adam Smith: An Inquiry into the Nature and Causes of the Wealth of Nations, Chapter 8](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3300/3300-h/3300-h.htm)

From the limited context of your question, it seems likely that Conlin is inviting his reader to consider some hypothesis in the light of Smith's view, and to contrast this negative correlation of happiness with income (*poor group = happy; rich group = less happy*) with the positive correlation that applies to individuals at any instant (*the richer you are the happier you feel*). It is this mismatch of correlations that lies at the heart of Richard Easterlin's paradox

> [Wikipedia: Easterlin Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easterlin_paradox)

From this standpoint, Conlin's  sentence is essentially about these two opposing views of measured correlations between perceived happiness and income. How happiness and income are measured is doubtless important and subject to controversy, but the measurements themselves are (at least in principle) amenable to statistical analysis. Hence Conlin advises his readers to keep in mind that statistical techniques are available and should be used to inform any analysis of happiness-income data and any conclusions about them.

Details of sampling statistics are not given in the sentence but are not crucial to your question or its answer.